# Updating a column to NULL returns empty column

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query

```
UPDATE tblPlayer 
SET Salary = NULL, 
    Status = "1" 
WHERE PlayerId=123
```

Instead of updating salary to `NULL` the it updates to an empty value

How do I get `NULL` instead of empty value?

Comment: Is NULL allowed on that field? Post table definition please...

Comment: Please, show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Describe your table.then only able to answer your question

Comment: Thanks for ur help Marco.....NULL was not allowed in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine with me

```
UPDATE tblPlayer 
SET    Salary = NULL, 
       Status = '1' 
WHERE  PlayerId = 123
```

I bet your `SALARY` has default value `''`

To alter the column, try this DDL

```
ALTER TABLE tblPlayer MODIFY Salary VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: But the default value should *not* be applied when doing an `UPDATE`, only when you don't supply a value during `INSERT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - [Looks like this is only the case in strict mode](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33699)

Comment: @MartinSmith: no kidding? MySQL really does that kind of thing? Geez, what where they smoking...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Although does say fixed in versions 5.1.24 and 6.0.5 on further reading.

Comment: Ah I didn't read right to the end. Could well be the issue then!